# Jasmine testing backbone views that use precompiled handlebars templates

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, jasmine

I am at a loss here.

I am looking to start adding tests for a site I am working on, using jasmine. I am unable to test any of my views though, because the templates being defined in the initialize functions for my views are pre-compiled handlebars templates that are being saved in an object.

My setup is so:

index.jade gets precompiled on my node server. This jade file had a bunch of

```
<script id="[name]" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
```

in it, with the snippets for each view. At the bottom of the index page is a jQuery $.each call:

```
  var templates = {};
  $("[type='text/x-handlebars-template']").each(function(index, div){
    templates[div.id] = Handlebars.compile(div.innerHTML);
  });
```

That loops through all these script tags, compiles them, and loads them into the templates object. I then save this object as an attribute of my main app model, to pass out to views as needed.

This works well for the site itself, but has proven a blocker for testing. When I try to load my views, they will not initialize as doing so requires the 'templates' object on the main model, with is populated from script tags pulled from the index. But index.html does not exist in my specRunner, short of me copy/pasting all the script tags into the spec runner each time I make a change.

I have no idea what the work-around here is. I'm sure it's something simple and I am too dense to see it, but I have been trying things out and looking up solutions for the better part of five hours, and have nothing to show for it.

I know I can compile the .jade file to .html with grunt, but past that I am unsure how to get the information from the html file to my SpecRunner.

Comment: Looks like `this.model` is undefined. You could check why it's not been set properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this was pretty complicated, but I got it working thanks to the magic that is grunt.

I set up grunt to use the grunt-contrib-jade and grunt-contrib-handlebars, which would auto compile my jade include pages to HBS, then compile those HBS files to JS.

```
jade: {
  compile: {
    options: {
      pretty: true
    },
    files: [ {
      cwd: "views/templates",
      src: "**/*.jade",
      dest: "spec/hbs",
      expand: true,
      ext: ".hbs"
    } ]
  }
},

handlebars: {
  compile: {
    options: {
      namespace: "compTemplates",
    },
    files: [ {
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'spec/hbs',
      src: '**/*.hbs',
      dest: 'spec/helpers',
      ext: '.js'
    } ]
  }
},
```

Each of these JS files would add their contents to the compTemplates object. These JS files were all pre-loaded into the Jasmine specRunner via Grunt, and the last helper (which I called 'z.js' to make sure it loaded last) included:

```
var templates = {};

for (var prop in window['compTemplates']) {
  var name = prop.split('/')[3];
  name = name.split('.')[0];
  templates[name] = window['compTemplates'][prop];
}
```

And voila! I had a templates object available to Jasmine that included all the handlebars templates ready to load into my views!